# How to config nginx to proxy x.example.com/a/xxx to a.example.com/xxx

Tags: nginx

My question is:

1. if I send a request http://x.example.com/a/sth, and here is my nginx proxy configuration:

   ```
   location ~ /([a-z0-9]+) {
       proxy_pass http://$1.example.com:8000/;
   }
   ```

   but it can't proxy to http://a.example.com/sth

how do I configure?

Comment: Have you tried adding `^` in front of the regex ? `location ~ ^/([a-z0-9]+)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `/a/` prefix from the URI before you pass it upstream. You can probably do this in the same regular expression.

For example:

```
location ~ ^/([a-z0-9]+)/(.*)$ {
    proxy_pass http://$1.example.com:8000/$2$is_args$args;
}
```

You may need to specify a [resolver](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver) directive, so that `nginx` can resolve the address of `$1.example.com`.

Comment: thank you for your reply, the "$1.example.com" is a real domain, and should configure resolver? and how to configure the resolver, and could you show me some example?